Is Lobachevsky acceptable here? $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\arcsin(\cos(2x))dx$
My original idea was to create a Lobachevsky integral using fractional parts since fractional parts are periodic. So I thought about making:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\left \{\frac{x}{\pi}\right \}dx$$
However, I realized that fractional parts are not continuous functions and that you need a continuous function in order to satisfy Lobachevsky's trick. Then I realized why not an absolute value version of it. Thankfully, $\arccos(\sin(x))$ helps perform that periodic absolute value function.
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\arccos(\sin(2x))dx$$
I just thought the $2x$ was necessary in order to satisfy the $\pi$-periodic function property.
Would Lobachevsky trick still work in this case?
Edit: I just realized another function. What about this one? Would it still apply? $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)\sin(2x)}{x}\left\{\frac{x}{\pi}\right\}dx$$

I would argue Lobachevsky does not require continuity and only requires the properties that periodicity together with continuity guarantees - namely bounded and of bounded variation.

$\left{\frac{x}{\pi}\right} = \frac{x}{\pi} - \lfloor \frac{x}{\pi} \rfloor = \operatorname{SawToothWave}(\frac{x}{\pi})$. I could not derive analytically the result of $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \operatorname{SawToothWave}(\frac{x}{\pi}) dx$, but it is numerically $\approx{0.527324}$. Whereas, by Lobachevsky method, $\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \operatorname{SawToothWave}(\frac{x}{\pi}) dx = \frac{\pi}{8}$.

I should clarify - bounded variation over a single period, not the whole domain of the function .

Really? Hmmmmm...

I'm not convinced continuity is always required for the Lobachevsky formula. A theorem states, "If a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x)=f(\pi+x)=f(\pi-x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,\pi/2]$, then $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}f\left(x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f\left(x\right)dx$." Proof here.

That being said, aside from numerical approximations not supporting the claims in the post, none of the integrals you've listed work because they don't satisfy the condition $f(x)=f(\pi+x)=f(\pi-x)$.

Ahhhh, got it!!

oh crap, I realized, I think I meant to put $\arcsin(\cos(2x))$, that should probably work now.

@Accelerator that form of Lobachevsky goes a bit too far and too rigid with conditions, because dropping that condition still gives an integral of the form $\int_0^\pi$ rather than exploiting extra symmetries to reduce it to $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Did you want to evaluate the integral in the title too?

Too lon for a comment.
$$I=\int \frac{\sin (x)}{x}\,\sin ^{-1}(\cos (2 x))\,dx$$ Using integration by parts, without any simplification,
$$I=\text{Si}(x) \sin ^{-1}(\cos (2 x))+2
   \sqrt{\sin ^2(2 x)} \csc (2 x) (x\,\text{Si}(x)+\cos (x))$$
Consider now
$$J_k=\int_{k \frac \pi 2}^{(k+1) \frac \pi 2}\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\,\sin ^{-1}(\cos (2 x))\,dx$$
Let
$$K_k=(-1)^k \,\frac{2}{  (2 k+1)\pi}\Bigg(J_k+2 \left(\cos \left(k\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-\sin \left(k\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\right) \Bigg)$$
$$K_k=\text{Si}\left( (k+1) \frac{\pi}{2} \right)-\text{Si}\left(k\frac{ \pi }{2}\right)$$
Now, what for
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty J_k$$
